# Is there any example of a man having a child without the help of a woman?

Tags: marriage, children

Child needn't be reproduced only by conventional sex. There are many other ways, such as Kunti and Madri having child from devtas. Similarly, Dronacharya was born when Bhardwaj ejaculated in a Drona-Patra. (But here again Bhardwaj was not unmarried but had a wife, also he ejaculated when a saw an Apsara)

Is there any example of a man having a child without the help of a woman?

In Mahabharata it is written that a man can't have a child without woman. But this is not said by Krishna. So, it can't be considered authentic. Many people in Mahabharata has said many things, those things needn't all be authentic.

> No man, even in anger, should ever do anything that is disagreeable to his wife; for happiness, joy, virtue and everything depend on the wife. Wife is the sacred soil in which the husband is born again, even the **Rishis cannot create men without women**.

— Adi Parva, Mahabharata Book, 1.74.50-51

Is there any example of an unmarried man having a child without the help of a woman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some of the versions of Rāmāyaṇa (**not** Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa), the famous vānara Hanumāna who was a brāhmacāri, had a son miraculously.  One of the tales goes like, after Hanumāna burnt the entire Laṅkā with his tail, due to tremendous heat emerging out of his body, he dived into the sea to cool himself. It's said that, in the process, a drop of his sweat fell inside the mouth of a large fish (probably crocodile as the name suggests) and that impregnated it. In some other versions, it was Hanumāna's reproductive fluid that fell along with the sweat inside makara's mouth. That's how Hanumāna's son named Makardhvaja was conceived.

In the bhakti tradition, Nābhādas, the author of *Bhaktamāla*, is described by Priyādāsa in his commentary Bhaktirasabodihī as *Hanumāna-vaṁśī*, but he never defines the term, and it has had many interpretations. Rūpkalā, in his commentary named Bhaktisudhāsvādu,  lists many interpretations of the term explains that Nābhādas was born from a drop of Hanumāna's sweat. He narrates the story of how Nābhā-jī came to be born in an unusual manner. One time, Śiva was instructing Hanumāna in Yoga. Due to Hanumāna's great mental effort, a drop of sweat fell from his body. This drop was caught by Śiva in a container, and in order to increase bhakti, he threw it down to earth where it became Nābhā-jī. That's one interpretation of Rūpkalā, as to why, Nābhādās is called *Hanumāna-vaṁśī*, and showing him to be an *ayonija* i.e. not born out of a woman's womb. (Hare, 2011)

The Kṛttivāsī Rāmāyaṇa, is one of the later versions of Rāmāyaṇa that was composed by the fifteenth century Bengali poet Kr̥ttivāsa. In that, there is another episode, when the famous king Dilīpa of the Ikṣvāku dynasty died, there was no heir to the kingdom. Śiva appeared and commanded the two widowed queens to make love together and blessed them that they would have a child that way. The two queens executed Śiva's order and one of them conceived a child named Bhagīratha, the famous ancestor of Rāma. 
So, Bhagīratha was born by the sexual congress of the widowed wives of the late king, and this episode is **not** there in the Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa. (Bose & Bose, 2013)

In the Kannada retelling of Rāmāyaṇa, Rāvaṇa (Ravul̥a), with his queen Mandodari was childless. So, Ravul̥a goes to the forest to perform austerities and meets Śiva, disguised as a yogin. Śiva gives him a magic mango and asks him to share it with his wife. Ravul̥a agreed, but Śiva said that he wouldn't do as said, and then will bear the repercussions of his own disobeying of the command. On the way to Laṅkā, Ravul̥a felt extremely hungry that he ate the mango himself, thereby fulfilling the prediction of the yogin. Thus, he became pregnant, and each day of pregnancy was equivalent to a month. At the ninth day, he sneezed and out came a little baby girl. The oracles said that the girl would be Ravul̥a's death and so he put her in a box and buried her in a field faraway.
The traditional bards who narrate this tale say that Sita was called
Sita because she was born when her father sneezed (in Kannada, sita
means sneeze). And in Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa, her name is Sītā (as in furrow) because she was found in a furrow when her foster father Janaka was ritually plowing the sacred fields. Thus, in the Kannada folk retelling of Rāmāyaṇa, Sītā is *ayonij*. (Ramanujan,1991)

Mahābhārata has an instance of an Ikṣvāku king named Yuvanāśva (who was already married) who gave birth to his son Māndhātā by himself. ( Sections CXXVI, LXII, XXIX )
The story went like this, Yuvanāśva who had retreated to the forest,  observed a fast once. But unfortunately, he suffered from terrible hunger as result and from a hermitage drank/ate some sacrificial water/butter from the jar/pot. Apprently, the water/butter was  not ordinary but a magical type which could make the one who drank it pregnant, and bestow them with a godly son. That's how Yuvanāśva became pregnant and gave birth to a godly son.

Droṇa, the teacher of Pāṇḍavas and Kauravas, was pot-born and untouched by a mother's womb. Sage Bhārdavāja had gone to river Gangā for offering *havis* when he saw an *apsarā* Ghr̥tācī draped in wet clothes with water dripping from them. When a gush of wind drew away her clothes, the sage was aroused and lost to ejection of some reproductive fluid, which he then put in a water pot (droṇa). Thus, Droṇa was born from a water pot and had no biological mother, as you mentioned.  Droṇa's brother-in-law Kr̥pa and Droṇa's wife Kr̥pī, too were not born of mother's womb. Their father Śaradvat, son of sage Gautama, was aroused upon seeing an apsarā sent by Indra to upset his concentration and practice. And as a result, he lost self-control and ejaculated. The semen fell on a reed and split in two halves, from which born twins, Kr̥pa and Kr̥pi.

Even in the accounts of these two motherless births of Droṇa and Kr̥pa-Kr̥pi, *women did play an indirect role of initial motivators*, that of facilitating arousal. There are some birth accounts in Mahābhārata, where women don't play a role at all. These births have been described as *ayonija* or non-uterine.
As is known, Drupada out of desire to avenge Droṇa for hs humiliation, scouted and found a suitable priest to perform a *yajña* for the generation of a son, who could slay Droṇa, At the end of *havana* (oblation), the priest told the queen 'a twin for you has appreared' and invited her to eat the *havis* (offering). The queen asked the priest to wait for a while so that she could go and wash her mouth and have a bath. But the proud priest refused to wait and put the *havis* into the ritual fire. From the fire of the sacrificial altar, sprang a boy, Dhr̥ṣṭadyumna and the princess Kr̥ṣṇā, better known as Draupadī, both having terrible heavenly announcements associated with their fate and purpose.

In Bhāgavata Purāṇa (IV.14-15), we see another case of *ayonij*, i.e. of Pr̥thu. Pr̥thu was churned out of the body (arms) of the late king Veṇa by the sages, so he was born without any female involvement.

In popular oral tradition, Rādhā, the beloved of Kr̥ṣṇa, is believed by some devotees to be *ayonija*, where they refer a folktale of her as a child being found laying on a lotus leaf by the wife of Vr̥ṣbhānu (in some versions by Vr̥ṣbhānu himself), who became her foster parents later. The Garga Saṁhitā is sometimes wrongly cited to support this, since I.8.6 clearly mentions Rādhā's entry into the womb of Vr̥ṣbhānu's wife. In Kr̥ṣṇa-Janma-Khaṇḍa (XVII. 146-147) of Brahmavaivarta Purāṇa though, Rādhikā (Rādhā) is born as the daughter of Kalāvatī and Vr̥ṣbhānu, but not out of the female womb as clearly mentioned in the verses. Thus she is *ayonij*, as per this text.

Popular tradition also talks about the birth of Ayyappa, where in some versions he is said to have been born by the union of Mohinī (the feminine form of Viṣṇu) and Śiva. This example can be problematic because Viṣṇu is considered a male but also has a feminine form in this case, so would he be considered a woman or man? There is another problem which is present in the conception of children by deities. It's hard to restrict the high ranking Purāṇic deities (trīmurti) to specific genders, for e.g. Śiva is seen in certain traditions as being both feminine and masculine, such as in his form Ardhanārīśvara. For e.g., Brahmā who with his mental power alone, without any involvement of women, produced his mind-born sons (mānasaputra) in the Viṣṇu and Bhāgavat Purāṇa. The problem with this is that we can't clearly call Brahmā or Viṣṇu or Śiva, no matter their form, as exactly male or female because they are beyond the gender categories of ordinary humans, and thus they are often personified in traditions with both male and female forms or genderless.

Most of the devas or some of those blessed with divine powers are beyond gender forms and so, many of them have the ability to take the forms of man or woman at will. Let there be a case, where a supposedly -male deity takes the form of a woman and has intercourse with a man, then they can have a child (for eg. Sugrīva was born this way). But would it still be considered a correct example? Because the deities don't have the limitation of ordinary hetro-sexual humans in which child can only (usually) be produced with the aid of the opposite sex.

Some of the examples from the epics given, are of the children of married people, or of women playing an indirect role (of motivators) in the birth (such as Droṇa). Makaradhvaja and Nābhādāsa are the only example given where they were born from womb. Although there is belief in bhakti traditions that Nābhādāsa is *ayonija*, but that is just a belief, since he is an actual historical person. As for the rest of the examples, none of these are born of actual intercourse or a female's womb, the only issue is that even though in some examples no woman was involved in the conceiving of their child (such as in the case of Yuvanāśva, Ravul̥a, Draupadī etc.), most of the men were married. The example from Kṛttivāsī Rāmāyaṇa of women themselves making love and having a baby without a man is interesting and unique even though it's not a correct example for the question, so it deserved mention according to me, on it being quite a peculiar birth. These are the only (semi) examples I could give. I hope it's not useless.

**References**

- Hare, J. P. (2011). *Garland of Devotees: Nābhādās’ “Bhaktamāl” and Modern Hinduism*. [Doctoral dissertation, Columbia University]. ProQuest Dissertations Publishing. https://doi.org/10.7916/D8VH5TN9
- Nābhādās, Priyādāsa, Rūpkalā (1962) *Bhaktamāla of Nābhāji with the Ṭīkā of Priyā-dāsa and with the commentary entitled with Bhaktisudhāsvādu of Śrī Sītārāma-Śaraṇa Bhagavān Prasād Rūpkalā*. (3rd ed.) Naval Kishore Press. Lucknow
- Bose, M., & Bose, S. (2013). Appendix 2: Kṛttivāsī Rāmāyaṇa. In *A Woman's Ramayana: Candrāvatī's Bengali Epic* (pp. 103-111). Routledge. https://doi.org/10.4324/9780203441480
- Ramanujan, A.K. (1991). 2. Three Hundred Rāmāyaṇas: Five Examples and Three Thoughts on Translation. In P. Richman (Ed.), *Many Rāmāyaṇas: The Diversity of a Narrative Tradition in South Asia* (pp. 22-49). University of California Press. https://doi.org/10.1525/9780520911758-004
- Ganguli, K.M. (1883-1896). *The Mahabharata of Krishna-Dwaipayana Vyasa* . Munshiram Manoharlal. https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan
- Chakrabarti, A., & Bandyopadhyay, S. (Eds.). (2014). Significance of the Early Parvans: Modes of Narration, Birth Stories and Seeds of Conflict. in *Mahabharata Now: Narration, Aesthetics, Ethics* (pp. 37-56). Routledge India. https://doi.org/10.4324/9781315662114
- Tagare, G.V. (1900). *The Bhagavata Purana*. (J.L. Shastri, Ed.) Ancient Indian Tradition and Mythology Series (Vol. 7- 11). Motilal Banarsidass. https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana
- Goswami, D. & Dasa, K. (2006). *Śrī Garga Saṁhitā*. Rupanuga Vedic College. https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/garga-samhita-english
- Nagar, S.L. (2005). Brahmavaivarta Purāṇa. (R. Chaturvedi, Ed.) Parimal Publications. https://archive.org/details/brahma-vaivarta-purana-all-four-kandas-english-translation

Answer (score 3):

> *Parāśara said:—*
> *From Brahmā, continuing to meditate, were born mind-engendered progeny, with forms and faculties derived from his corporeal nature; embodied spirits, produced from the person of that all-wise deity. All these beings, front the gods to inanimate things, appeared as I have related to you, being the abode of the three qualities: but as they did not multiply themselves, Brahmā created other mind-born sons, like himself; namely, Bhrigu, Pulastya, Pulaha, Kratu, Aṅgiras, Marīci, Dakṣa, Atri, and Vaśiṣṭha: these are the nine Brahmas (or Brahma ṛṣis) celebrated in the Purāṇas.(Sri Vishnu Maha Puran 1:7:1-5).*

So, while creating his mind born sons (mānas putra), Lord Brahma was unmarried and the sons were created purely through yoga or meditation.

But actually, there is no particular answer to this question because every creature be it male or female is born of Prakriti so half of them are male and half female. That's why wives' are also called as Vamangi means possessing left half of their husband's body or Ardhandini. Just like Ardhanareshwara Bhagawan. So, if we go by the scriptures, no examples will be correct.

> *न हि कश्चित्क्षणमपि जातु तिष्ठत्यकर्मकृत् |
> कार्यते ह्यवश: कर्म सर्व: प्रकृतिजैर्गुणै: || b.g. 3.5 ||*
>
> *There is no one who can remain without action even for a moment. Indeed, all beings are compelled to act by their qualities born of material (motherly) nature (the three guṇas).*

Again,

**Brihad Arankyaka Upanishad.:**

> *स वै नैव रेमे तस्मादेकाकी न रमते । **स द्वितीयमैच्छत् स हैतावानास यथा स्त्रीपुमासौ सम्परिष्वक्तौ । स इममेवाऽऽत्मानं द्वेधाऽपातयत्। ततः पतिश्च पत्नी चाभवताम् । तस्मादिदमर्धबृगलमिव स्व इति ह स्माऽऽह याज्ञवल्क्यस् तस्मादयमाकाशः स्त्रिया पूर्यत एव** । ता समभवत् ततो मनुष्या अजायन्त ॥ ३ ॥*
>
> *I-iv-3: He (Purusha) was not at all happy. Therefore people (still) are not happy when alone. **He desired a mate. He became as big as man and wife embracing each other. He parted this very body into two. From that came husband and wife. Therefore, said Yajnavalkya, this (body) is one-half of oneself, like one of the two halves of a split pea.** Therefore this space is indeed filled by the wife. He was united with her. From that men were born.*

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: "even the Rishis cannot create men without women" - this is for humans and doesn't necessarily apply to gods. Brahma is god (not human)

Comment: Yes, Lord Brahma is a god no doubt but the question is asking is there any unmarried man not unmarried human. Plus, when you consider a rishi, rishis are called as self realised entity. When one knows brahman they becomes brahman themselves. So, in a sense rishis are also gods not human.

Comment: "Rishi" may be different from human but not same as god because gods are immortal due to nectar but a rishi can be killed eg jamadagni killed by arjuna, etc. Brahma is like >= gods

Comment: **Vajra Suchika Upanishad.:** 
9. Who indeed then is brAhmaNa ? Whoever he may be, he who has directly realised his AtmA and who is directly cognizant, like the myrobalan in his palm, of his AtmA, that is without a second, that is devoid of class and actions, that is free from the faults of faults of the six stains (hunger, thirst, grief, confusion, old age, and death) and the six changes (birth, existence etc),

Comment: that is of the nature of truth, knowledge, bliss and eternity, that is without any change in itself, that is the substratum of all the kalpas, that exists penetrating all things that pervades everything within and without as AkAsh, that is of nature of undivided bliss, .

Comment: that cannot be reasoned about and that is known only by direct cognition . He who by the reason of having obtained his wishes is devoid of the faults of thirst after worldly objects and passions, who is the possessor of the qualifications beginning with sAma (dama, uparati, titikShA, samadhana, sraddha), who is free from emotion, malice, thirst after worldly objects, desire, delusion, etc., whose mind is untouched by pride, egoism, etc., who possesses all these qualities and means- he only is the brAhmaNa.

Comment: Such is the opinion of the veda, the smritis, the itihAsa, and the purANa-s . Otherwise one cannot obtain the status of a brahmaNa . One should meditate on his Atma as sachchidAnanda, and the non-dual brahman . Yea, one should meditate on his Atma as the sachchidAnanda brahman . Such is the upaniShad

Comment: So, A brahmana (Vipra, Rishi, Muni, etc are brahmana because they are self realised. **Mundaka Upanishad.:** As, for Jamdagni yes he was killed by Arjuna of thousands hands

स यो ह वै तत् परमं ब्रह्म वेद ब्रह्मैव भवति नास्याब्रह्मवित्कुले भवति । तरति शोकं तरति पाप्मानं गुहाग्रन्थिभ्यो विमुक्तोऽमृतो भवति ॥९॥

III-ii-9: Anyone who knows that supreme Brahman becomes Brahman indeed. In his line is not born anyone who does not know Brahman. He overcomes grief, and rises above aberrations; and becoming freed from the knots of the heart, he attains immortality.

Comment: Yes, jamdagni was killed by Arjuna,. So, what he got moksha. Even in daksha yagna many gods were kiled. Though were later revived. But, still getting moksha means becoming immortal only. Even during pralaya devas (gods not demi-gods) achieves moksha.

Comment: My intention was not to dispute but it seems you got offended ! The word "brahmana" has multiple meanings depending on context. All above upanishadic verses are fine for supreme (moksha) but are they relevant to the context ? may be not because here we are just discussing a lower level topic i.e. procreation.

Comment: Even my intention is not to dispute n m not offended m just correcting u for which u seems offended. And as for is everything related yes damn sure they are just like a spider web. U think procreation is a low level topic.? But its not as that's how everything comes into beings. The brahmana i was talking about was varna brahman. Don't you think its relevant for the topic as u r saying rishis r human n me n scriptures r saying no they are not. Let me give u an example of rishis wrt brahman from the same Upanishad.

Comment: **Vajra Suchika Upanishad.:**
*5. Then is a class the brAhmaNa ? No . Since many **rishis** have sprung from other castes and orders of creation - RishyashRi.nga was born of deer; kaushika, of kusha grass; jAmbuka of a jackal; vAlmiki of valmIka (an ant-hill); vyAsa of a fisherman's daughter; gautama, of the posteriors of a hare; vasishtha of Urvasi (a celestial nymph in the court of Indra); and agastya of a water-pot; thus have we heard . Of these, many rishis outside the caste have stood first among the teachers of divine wisdom; therefore a class is not the brAhmaNa.*

Comment: I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd.. cya tc.

Comment: "u r saying rishis r human" - in my first comment i wanted to say rishi but human was a typo from my side which i corrected in my next comment ""Rishi" may be different from human". Anyways rishis have grades (maharishi, brahmarishi, etc.) from story of vishwamitra in valmiki ramayana, so the inability to produce child without woman might apply to the lowest level rishi only  https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga63/bala_63_frame.htm  https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga65/bala_65_frame.htm

Comment: As i have given you verse in the Upanishad vyasa, valmiki n all are not said maha rishis but only rishis. Shrutis>Smritis. Also, as i have mentioned in my ans inself every men is half women.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141604/discussion-between-arvind-c-and-savdy).

Comment: I think any hindu will know that krishna is an avatar of vishnu be it advance or unadvance cz its our culture n we hv listened ts stories frm childhood. If you r talking about people from other cultures then I don't care. So, be it people like u or me. In sanatanis we may have different ishta devas but our roots are still same. And if someone is so naive that they don't knows this things then i guess they should start from scriptures itself instead of bits n pieces from here and there n i was not saying that u r insulting rishis i said the words used are not good. Anyways,goodbye man again.Tc.